# How can I escape double quotes in Bash?

Tags: bash

I want to escape double quotes in Bash. I followed the following approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
this is a  \"number\"!
```

But is there another way?

Comment: `echo 'this is a "number"'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU Bash:

```
echo -e "this is a \x22number\x22"
```

Output:

```
this is a "number"
```

Comment: Better yet, `printf "this is a \42number\42\n"`, which will work in any POSIX-compatible shell. (`\42` is the character whose ASCII value is 42 in *octal*.)

Answer (score 9):

You can enclose the double quotes in single quotes:

```
echo '"'hola'"'
```

Or alternatively the whole text, including the double quotes:

```
echo '"hola"'
```

Comment: thanks for the support this works well

Comment: while this will work it won't interpolate vars

Comment: You wouldn't put the parameter expansion inside the single quotes, but you'd have to quote them as well. This approach quickly gets unreadable:, e.g., `echo '"'"$string"'"'`