# creating docker images in two git environments

Tags: git, shell, docker, github

I am new to docker and I am trying to set up a QA environment of airflow(I already have a production). This is how I defined in the entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TRY_LOOP="20"
SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes

BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [ "$BRANCH" == 'master' ]
then
   "${REDIS_HOST:="airflow-celery.xxxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com"}"
else [ "$BRANCH" == 'QA' ]
   "${REDIS_HOST:="qa-airflow-celery.xxxx.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com"}"
fi

: "${REDIS_PORT:="6379"}"

if [ "$BRANCH" == 'master' ]
then
  "${POSTGRES_HOST:="airflow-database.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"}"
  "${POSTGRES_USER:="airflow"}"
else [ "$BRANCH" == 'QA' ]
  "${POSTGRES_HOST:="qa-airflow-database.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"}"
  "${POSTGRES_USER:="airflow"}"
fi
```

The build runs successfully but it throws a following error when I try to run the docker container and it never starts

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 6: git: command not found
/entrypoint.sh: line 11: qa-airflow-celery.xxxxx.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com: command not found
/entrypoint.sh: line 21: qa-airflow-database.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

I'd really appreciate If i can some help with it.

Comment: It seems like the image of the Docker container you're using does not have Git installed. What image are you using?

Comment: @Omer: I am using docker airflow image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 2 errors happens because you have **double quotes inside double quotes**.

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 11: qa-airflow-celery.xxxxx.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com: command not found
/entrypoint.sh: line 21: qa-airflow-database.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

I think you can get rid of the outer quotes in all your bash file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TRY_LOOP="20"
SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes

BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [ "$BRANCH" == 'master' ]
then
   ${REDIS_HOST:="airflow-celery.xxxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com"}
else [ "$BRANCH" == 'QA' ]
   ${REDIS_HOST:="qa-airflow-celery.xxxx.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com"}
fi

: ${REDIS_PORT:="6379"}

if [ "$BRANCH" == 'master' ]
then
  ${POSTGRES_HOST:="airflow-database.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"}
  ${POSTGRES_USER:="airflow"}
else [ "$BRANCH" == 'QA' ]
  ${POSTGRES_HOST:="qa-airflow-database.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"}
  ${POSTGRES_USER:="airflow"}
fi
```

If this doesn't work, go with this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35586785/7804876

The first error is because **airflow's image does not contain git**.

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 6: git: command not found
```

The easy way is to add to `entrypoint.sh` file the git installation command as the first line. 
For Debian distribution:

```
apt install -y git
```

If RHEL distribution:

```
yum -y install git
```

The downside of this approach is that the installation takes some time.
You better **add git dependency to the image**:

1. Run the image with your `docker run` command but without `--entrypoint entrypoint.sh`.
2. Check container-id
   `docker ps`
   For the sake of the example the container-id is `c3f279d17e0a`
3. `docker exec -it c3f279d17e0a bash`
4. Install git manually with apt/yum as mentioned above, then detach the bash by typing `ctrl+p` and `ctrl+q` after each other.
5. Commit new image
       `docker commit c3f279d17e0a airflow-git:version1`

   > It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings into a new image. This allows you to debug a container by running an interactive shell, or to export a working dataset to another server. Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a documented and maintainable way.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

**Now your have the image `airflow-git:version1`**, run it with your original run command with `--entrypoint entrypoint.sh` and it should work.